# Using typescript decorators in multiple files

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-decorator

i'm developing a script in typescript that uses decorators, the decorator function add the decorated class to a list, when an event happens a method inside the class will be called like a callback. It all works if there are multiple decorated classes inside the same file but if i put a class with the decorator inside another file it doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
export class Person {
  sayRole(): void {
    console.log("generic");
  }
}

@PersonDecorator("Bob")
export class Student extends Person {
  sayRole(): void {
    console.log("student");
  }
}

var people = new Array<Person>();
function PersonDecorator(name:string) {
  return (target: any) => {
    (<Person>target).sayRole();
  };
}
```

Comment: `it doesn't work` is not much to work with. What doesn't work? What do you mean with "it doesn't work"? Do you get errors? If not, what then? ... we need a bit more than "it doesn't work."

Comment: decorators can be imported and exported as any other objects in javascript but when I starting your code in single file I see `TypeError: target.sayRole is not a function`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with your person decorator? When do you expect sayRole to be called?